# wordpress. Is it possible to have dynamic content?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, dynamic, wordpress-theming

Is it possible to have dynamic content in wordpress? I know that navigation, footer, and sidebar is dynamic. But what about the content? What if my content is within a 3 col grid? How can I add a 3 col grid to wordpress if I am only provided with one paragraph box within editing page? If i add the html code in my php file, it will be static and not dynamic. I have studied resources and not found a solution. In result I am asking here to clarify. Therefore, how can I make the content within the body dynamic?

Some of the sources I studied
[Nav Walker](https://github.com/wp-bootstrap/wp-bootstrap-navwalker)

[Dynamic Template](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/dynamic-page-templates-in-wordpress-1--cms-28366)

Comment: You can use visual composers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It totally depends on your needs and the time you can spend on this. Here are some guidelines:

1. If you always going to **follow a specific layout** for a page then you can have meta boxes for the content and style is applied by default.

   **Examples:**
   Advance Custom Fields (ACF) is most popular and easy to use. Alternatively, you can create custom meta boxes.
2. If you wanted to **give more control** then you can create your own layout snippets and define as shortcodes.

   **Examples:**
   In one of my recent project, I create my own shortocodes and that can be used in any page and will be automatically formatted before displaying on frontpage like

   ```
   [video_right]
   [testimonial]some content[/testimonial]
   [one_fifth]columns[/one_fifth]
   ```

BTW, you can also use any visual builder like Visual Composer etc.